# How to open and read a file in the src/my/package folder?

Tags: android

I would like to load the contents of a text file in a String.
The text file should stay in the same folder `src/my/package` as the `.java`.

However, I can't find the path to this file:
I have tried:

```
File f = new File("src/my/package/file.js"); 
File f = new File("file.js");
```

and many others but nothing worked.

What is the correct path to my file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To open files located on the classpath, use the [`Class.getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) family of methods. They work even if the file is inside a `jar` file with your classes. So something like

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/my/package/file.js");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! A detail: the path should start with /, so it should be:     InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/my/package/file.js");